Impact of Enabling SSR on Server Resources Under Load Conditions
I have implemented Server-Side Rendering (SSR) in an Angular application and observed significant improvements in performance metrics on the client side. Specifically, I have seen an 80% improvement in "Eliminate Render Blocking Resources" and around a 50% improvement in "UI Layout Rendering" during debugging.
Now, I am looking to understand the impact of SSR on server-side resources, especially under load conditions. How does enabling SSR affect server load, memory usage, and CPU utilization? I am interested in understanding how these changes manifest in a production environment where the server is handling a high volume of requests.
I have reviewed client-side performance metrics and confirmed that SSR provides substantial improvements in user experience. However, I am seeking insights into the server-side impact of these improvements. Specifically, I would like to know:
What kind of increase in server resource consumption (CPU, memory, etc.) should be expected with SSR under various load conditions?
Are there any best practices or optimizations that can help manage server resource usage effectively when using SSR?
Any insights or experiences regarding server-side resource management with SSR would be greatly appreciated.
My hosting environment is IIS.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
